# "Error: 'by' is NA" using ddply and rollingMean

Tags: r, plyr, openair

I'm trying to calculate 8-hour rolling means using a *ddply* + *rollingMean* command on a pollutant data frame that looks something like this:

```
df1
date                co      code
2000-01-17 01:00:00 0.97000 42
2000-01-17 02:00:00 0.97000 42
2000-01-17 03:00:00 0.98000 42
2000-01-17 04:00:00 0.98000 42
2000-02-04 08:00:00 0.70000 42
2000-02-04 09:00:00 1.40000 42
2000-02-04 10:00:00 1.51000 42
2000-02-04 11:00:00 1.49000 43
2000-02-04 12:00:00 1.98000 43
2000-02-04 15:00:00 1.61000 43
2000-02-04 16:00:00 1.88000 43
2000-02-04 17:00:00 1.64000 43
2000-02-04 18:00:00 1.62000 43
2000-02-04 19:00:00 2.05000 43`
```

As you can see, the time series isn't complete (that's why I'm using openair's *rollingMean*, which treats data according to a "date" column), and there's different station "codes" (that I separated using *ddply* because *rollingMean* doesn't work with more than one station).

However, when I use this code:

```
> pd<-ddply(df1,.(code),function(df){df<-rollingMean(df,pollutant="co",
             width=8,new.name="rolling",data.thresh=75);return(df)})`
```

The return is:

> Error: 'by' is NA

Can anyone help me with this error?
Thanks in advance.

*PS: Using a similar "o3" data frame like this:*

```
> head(var2)
date                o3    codigo
2000-01-01 01:00:00 23.25      1
2000-01-01 02:00:00 20.08      1
2000-01-10 16:00:00 63.67      1
2000-01-10 17:00:00 80.64      1
2000-01-10 18:00:00 86.48      1
2000-01-10 19:00:00 61.48      1
```

*and this command:*

```
pd<-ddply(var2,.(codigo),function(df){df<-rollingMean(df,pollutant="o3",
           width=8,new.name="medmov",data.thresh=75);return(df)})
```

*the code works just fine, showing:*

```
> head(pd)
date                o3    codigo  medmov
2000-01-01 01:00:00 23.25      1      NA
2000-01-01 02:00:00 20.08      1      NA
2000-01-01 03:00:00 22.31      1      NA
2000-01-01 04:00:00 23.02      1 22.1650
2000-01-01 05:00:00 12.40      1 20.2120
2000-01-01 06:00:00 11.67      1 16.2575
```

Comment: could you edit the question to give an example of how you expect the output to look

Comment: @Camila Lopes Couldn't reproduce the error, It works fine for me using the example showed.  Please use `dput` to show the example dataset that creates the error.  For example `dput(head(df1,20)`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

@akrun, my data frame is huge (1490375 obs. and 61 different stations), so I tried to use `dput` with a subset of it. Realising that with some subsets the command worked, I started to test different sizes to find the exact part of the data that caused the error.
Getting a 100 obs. data frame, I saw that a particular station had a single observation, not only on the subset but on the entire data frame! (a simple `summary(df1$code)`could find that quickly. My bad)
Excluding this observation, the command worked smoothly.

So probably this type of error occurs when *rollingMean* can't find enough observations to calculate the rolling mean. I would never guess that.

Anyway, thanks @akrun and @jalapic. :)

Comment: Glad to know that you were able to figure it out.